# Creating a menu similar to Google Plus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to achieve a responsive menu similar to Google Plus, where the main menu options are added to or removed from the "more" drop down as the window is resized.

The menu I have currently looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
// JQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.drop-menu").click(function () {
        $('#drop-menu').toggle();
    });
});

<!-- HTML -->
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" class="drop-menu">More</a>
      <ul id="drop-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul></li>
</ul>

/* CSS */ 
#navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#navigation li a:link, #navigation li a:visited, #navigation li a:active {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #27383F;
  color: #CCC8C0;
}
#navigation li a:hover, #navigation li a.active {
  background-color: #2C3C53;
}

#drop-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#drop-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bzrfonb/)

Currently, when the browser window is re-sized the menu options collapse as follows:

[image]

However, the below image is my desired result:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to accomplish this without media queries? More specifically:

1. How can I dynamically detect whether the window size is large enough or too small to contain the `li` tags in the main navigation on a single line?
2. How do I swap the `li` tags between one menu and the other?

Comment: I'm quite interested in a non-JavaScript solution.

Comment: I have a question based on yours here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236532/google-plus-like-menu-not-working-on-re-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not using `media-queries` I think you can use jQuery `$( window ).width();` which will return  width of browser viewport.. It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.drop-menu").click(function () {
        $('#drop-menu').toggle();
    });
    if($( window ).width() < $("#navigation > li").length * (120 + 5)){
        //5px is the approximation of the gap between each <li>
        var html = $("#navigation > li").last().prev().html();
        $("#navigation > li").last().prev().remove();
        $("#drop-menu").append(html);
    }
    var bigger = $("#navigation > li").length + 1;
    var smaller = $("#navigation > li").length;
    $( window ).resize(function() {
      if($( window ).width() <= smaller * (120 + 5)){
          //5px is the approximation of the gap between each <li>
          var html = $("#navigation > li").last().prev().html();
          if(html != undefined){
              $("#navigation > li").last().prev().remove();
              $("#drop-menu").prepend("<li>"+html+"</li>");
              bigger = $("#navigation > li").length + 1;
              smaller = $("#navigation > li").length;
          }
      }
      if($( window ).width() >= bigger * (120 + 5)){
          //5px is the approximation of the gap between each <li>
          var html = $("#drop-menu > li").first().html();
          if(html != undefined){
              $("#drop-menu > li").first().remove();
              $("#navigation > li").last().before("<li>"+html+"</li>");
              bigger = $("#navigation > li").length + 1;
              smaller = $("#navigation > li").length;
          }
      };
    });
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zangbbjd/2/), I believe it's not the perfect result.. But, I believe you can use it as your starting point.. Hope it helps..

Comment: This is great, I have a question based on this question and it was before this I saw this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236532/google-plus-like-menu-not-working-on-re-size